# "Circular reference involving containing bean" error while starting tomcat in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, circular-reference, nosuchmethoderror

I did a "mvn clean package" which downloaded all the external dependencies and was successful. There are jars with overlapping classes and I see that above error when I try to run my application using IntelliJ IDEA. Same result on eclipse too. How can I solve this issue?

I also see

"Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:" of a method but I see that class in multiple jars downloaded by maven which are under /root/.m2/repository folder. A couple of those jars have same exact package path and name.

Please let me know if I have to provide more details on this issue.

Comment: It looks like the class that was being used in my application is present in two different jars and tomcat is picking the wrong one. For everybody else it is picking that correct one. I will need to figure out how to make my tomcat server pick the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an actual bug. Different implementations are provided with same class and root package by two different jars (It's a no-no). But still not sure why my VirtualBox VMs are loading that class from one jar 100% of the time while for all others in my team that class is loaded from the correct jar.